# In typescript how do I extend a global interface with a declared function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am working on a legacy javascript project and currently adding typescript declaration *.d.ts* files for some of the more popular functions for better vscode type definitions.

Current setup includes multiple overloads on said function and it returns a set value based on those overload options.

```
declare function createChild(type: "div", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement): HTMLDivElement;
declare function createChild(type: "span", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement): HTMLSpanElement;
declare function createChild(type: "input", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement): HTMLInputElement;
```

What I'd like is to also add the `.createChild` function to the HTMLElements that get returned.

Potentially it could be written as

```
interface CreateChild_DivElement extends HTMLDivElement {
    createChild: createChild
}
```

and I'd replace the `HTMLDivElement` with `CreateChild_DivElement` but it fails due to the declared function not adding properly to the interface *(tooltip shows the value as any)*.

What I was hoping for is adding a varaible to a typescript interface.

```
interface CustomElement<Original> {
   ...Original,
   createChild: createChild,
}
```

and use it like the following example

```
declare function createChild(type: "div", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement): CustomElement<HTMLDivElement>;
```

Obviously this doesn't work and is merely and example.

How do I get the declared .createChild function as part of the HTMlElement's that get returned.

After browsing through some unanswered typescript questions I came accross a type declaration I didn't know existed. I now ended up with this complete code. Works but it's definetly not pretty. Is there a better way to acheive this?

```
export = createChild;

// Declare the functions
declare function createChild(type: "div", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement): CustomElement<HTMLDivElement>;
declare function createChild(type: "span", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement): CustomElement<HTMLSpanElement>;
declare function createChild(type: "input", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement): CustomElement<HTMLInputElement>;
declare function createChild(type: "p", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement): CustomElement<HTMLParagraphElement>;
declare function createChild(type: "a", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement): CustomElement<HTMLAnchorElement>;
declare function createChild(type: "img", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement): CustomElement<HTMLImageElement>;
declare function createChild(type: "ul", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement): CustomElement<HTMLUListElement>;
declare function createChild(type: "li", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement): CustomElement<HTMLLIElement>;
declare function createChild(type: "hr", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement): CustomElement<HTMLHRElement>;
declare function createChild(type: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement): CustomElement<HTMLHeadingElement>;
declare function createChild(type: string, options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement): CustomElement<HTMLElement>;

type CustomElement<Original> = Original & {
    createChild: ((type: "div", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement) => CustomElement<HTMLDivElement>) &
    ((type: "span", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement) => CustomElement<HTMLSpanElement>) &
    ((type: "input", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement) => CustomElement<HTMLInputElement>) &
    ((type: "p", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement) => CustomElement<HTMLParagraphElement>) &
    ((type: "a", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement) => CustomElement<HTMLAnchorElement>) &
    ((type: "img", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement) => CustomElement<HTMLImageElement>) &
    ((type: "ul", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement) => CustomElement<HTMLUListElement>) &
    ((type: "li", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement) => CustomElement<HTMLLIElement>) &
    ((type: "hr", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement) => CustomElement<HTMLHRElement>) &
    ((type: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement) => CustomElement<HTMLHeadingElement>) &
    ((type: string, options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement) => CustomElement<HTMLElement>);
};

type ElementNames = 'div' | 'span' | 'input' | 'p' | 'i' | 'a' | 'img' | 'ul' | 'li' | 'hr' | 'h1' | 'h2' | 'h3' | 'h4' | 'h5' | 'h6';


/**
 * The options for create child
 */
interface CreateChild_Options {
    id?: string,
    classList?: string[],
    style?: CSSStyleDeclaration | string,
    childNodes?: (CreateChild_Create | CreateChild_Child)[],
    on: {
        click: (this: HTMLElement, ev: MouseEvent, options: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions) => any,
        contextmenu: (this: HTMLElement, ev: MouseEvent, options: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions) => any,
        keyup: (this: HTMLElement, ev: KeyboardEvent, options: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions) => any,
        keydown: (this: HTMLElement, ev: KeyboardEvent, options: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions) => any,
        keypress: (this: HTMLElement, ev: KeyboardEvent, options: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions) => any,
        focus: (this: HTMLElement, ev: FocusEvent, options: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions) => any,
        blur: (this: HTMLElement, ev: FocusEvent, options: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions) => any,
        focusin: (this: HTMLElement, ev: FocusEvent, options: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions) => any,
        focusout: (this: HTMLElement, ev: FocusEvent, options: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions) => any,
        [key: string]: (this: HTMLElement, ev: Event, options: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions) => any,
    }
};


/**
 * Used create child to create and append a new child element
 */
interface CreateChild_Create {
    type: ElementNames,
    options?: CreateChild_Options,
}


/**
 * appends a child element that was created already
 */
interface CreateChild_Child {
    child: HTMLElement | HTMLNode
}
```

Comment: In a module, a file containing a top level `import` or `export`, all declarations are scoped to that module. To declare ambient globals like your `createChild` from within a module, TypeScript provides the `declare global` construct. Ex: `import x from 'y'; declare global { function createChild(type: "div", ...) }`

Comment: @AluanHaddad I can't seem to catch what you are putting down. I thought declaring a global was to add a varaible to the window/global scope. I can't seem to figure out how I'd use a global in this case.

Comment: I'll provide an example

Answer (score 1):

The file containing your function declarations is a module.

A module is a file containing one or more top level `import` or `export` statements.

Your file contains

```
export = createChild;
```

making it a module.

All constructs lexically specified in a module, be they values or types, ambient or not, are scoped to that module.

However, sometimes we need to reach out from within a module to add something to the enclosing scope, which for a module is the global scope.

For values, we do as you say and assign to properties of `window` or `global` or `globalThis`. As TypeScript adds types to JavaScript it needs a syntax to enable us to do the same thing for types.

That syntax is the `declare global` block.

In the code below it's applied to your example,

```
export = createChild;

declare global {
  function createChild(type: "div", options?: CreateChild_Options, node?: HTMLElement): CustomElement<HTMLDivElement>;
}
```